# Sign BizTalk WCF Response with X509 certificate

Tags: wcf, biztalk

1. I have deployed Orchestration as WCF service.
2. I've implemented WCF CustomIsolated, BasicHttp binding,
   TransportWithMessageCredential scurity.
3. I am getting Signed message (with WS-Scurity Header).
4. But the response which is going back to client requires to be signed by
   my Signing certificate. As of now Response going back to client only
   contains a timestamp in the Security header .

How to configure the WCF response to be signed with the Signing Certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You must first install the certificate on the computer running BizTalk Server. To do this you can try following these steps:

1. On the windows start menu click 'Run', type mmc and press enter;
2. A 'Console1' windows will apear. Click on the 'File' menu and then on 'Add/Remove Snap-in';
3. In the 'Add or Remove Snap-ins' dialog box, in the Available snap-ins list, double-click Certificates. Check 'Computer account', click next and then click finish.
4. Back in the 'Add or Remove Snap-ins' window click OK;
5. In the Console1 window expand Certificates, right-click 'Other People'->All Tasks->Import;
6. On the wizzard click next, and on the 'File to import' page click browse;
7. Browse to your certificate location and open the certificate.
8. Click next, next again and then click finish;
9. On the Wizard message box click OK;

Now you can configure your Send Port in Biztalk Server. Double-click the port, and on the left side click 'Certificates'. Choose your certificate and confirm.

You should now be able to sign your outgoing message